# Display current year using external javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble updating the current year using js from an external file. The year in the html doesn't update to display the current year. Here's my html code;

```
<p>
    Copyright &copy; <span id="year">year</span>. All rights reseverved.
</p>

<script src="./js/shared.js"></script>
```

And here's my js code;

```
const year = document.querySelector('#year');

function date() {
    year.innerHTML = new Date()
};
```

What am I doing wrong here, and what's the right way to achieve my goal?

Comment: You want just the year but it is showing the entire date? Maybe you want `new Date().getFullYear()`

Comment: It does not update the year in the span

Comment: yes, but when did you call your `date()` function?

Comment: `new Date().getFullYear()` also doesn't update the year in my html

Comment: I know, you need to call your `date()` function... But also, need to specify in your questionwhat is the problem, not just say "having trouble". Being more specific could help us to help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I called the `date()` function"?

Comment: you have a function: `function date(){...`  when do you call this function to it execute what is is supposed to execute? You must call it to it works. Something like: `function date(){...}; date();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to add function invocation:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
      const year = document.querySelector('#year');

      function date() {
         year.innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();
      };

      date();
  }
```

Comment: This one did not work on my code. The current year still isn't updated

Comment: @Sags try to wrap into 'DOMContentLoaded'